# После каждого обновления windows 10, изменения оптимизирующие работу ssd возвращаются в исходное состояние

Tags: windows-10, ssd

После каждого обновления windows 10, изменения оптимизирующие работу ssd возвращаются в исходное состояние.
Система на ssd + дополнительно hdd.
Произвел настойки системы для ssd (перенес файл подкачки и пользовательские файлы на hdd, отключил индексацию, а так-же произвел другие настройки для оптимизации ssd).
После каждого обновления windows 10, например, возвращается индексация на системном диска (ssd), файл подкачки. 
Проблема в том, что это происходит на нескольких машинах, обновления на которых проходит не равномерно и отлавливать изменения проблематично.
Может кто сталкивался с решением этой проблемы?

Comment: Проблема заключается из-за обновления windows, чтобы её решить, необходимо не обновлять windows по каждому её запросу. Из обновления в обновление они не приподносят ничего существенного что могло бы хоть как-то улучшить производительность. С 1903 версии уже можно забыть про мазохизм с обновлениями и ждать 20ХХ.

Comment: А зачем отключать индексацию на SSD и какие другие настройки оптимизации? Да, обновления лучше отключить.

Comment: Тут ощущается некоторое противоречие. Как правило, SSD нужен для того, чтобы _ускорить_ работу системы. Перенос же файла подкачки с SSD на HDD по очевидным причинам _замедлит_ работу системы. Если же стоит цель не ускорить работу, а сохранить ресурс SSD, то тогда надо не ограничиваться полумерами, а всю систему ставить на HDD.